# How to split vuetify-text-field-label over 2 lines

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js

I have a vuetify text field. The label is too long for mobile devices. Is it possible to automatically wrap the text. I tried using div and p, like so (link on [codepen](https://codepen.io/gaydiramlu/pen/MWmrPqM?editors=101))

```
<div id="app">
  <v-app id="inspire">
    <v-form>
      <v-container>
        <v-text-field>
          <template v-slot:label>
            <div><p>First line of text.</p></div><div><p>Second line of text</p></div>
          </template>
        </v-text-field>
      </v-container>
    </v-form>
  </v-app>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `<span>` elements with `display: inline-block`.

```css
@keyframes example {
  0% {width: 310px;}
  50% {width: 290px;}
  100% {width: 310px;}
}

#wrapper {
  word-wrap: normal;
  padding: 0 10px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  animation-name: example;
  animation-duration: 5s;
    animation-timing-function: sine;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}

.sentence {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <p><span class="sentence">First line of text.</span> <span class="sentence">Second line of text.</span></p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

If the information is necessary, I would use a [hint](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/text-fields/#hint). Google [material design](https://material.io/components/text-fields#anatomy) suggests that multi-line or long labels are bad practices:
[image]

Comment: Is it possible to have hyperlinks (a-anchor) in the hint?

Comment: @nurdunertu, no, only string values. There is no slot for it. Why do you need to show an anchor?